# Why std:map can't accept a pointer as key-value?

Tags: c++

I am trying to **realize a jni function putting a mutex object in a map**. 
When compiling, I get the error "...because jni pass a pointer" and I canmot convert in the argument.

Why a `std:map` cannot accept a pointer as key-value?

The instruction which gives the error is this:

```
std::pair<_jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex> v = 
   std::pair<_jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>(*ref, *new boost::fibers::recursive_mutex());

#include <jni.h>
#include <map>
#include "ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.h"
#include <boost/fiber/recursive_mutex.hpp>
std::map<_jobject, boost::fibers::recursive_mutex> mutexes;
boost::fibers::recursive_mutex lock;
// ‘std::pair<_jobject*, boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>::
//pair(_jobject&, boost::fibers::recursive_mutex&)’
// mutexes.insert(std::pair<jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>((_jobject&)ref, *new boost::fibers::recursive_mutex()));

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL Java_ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock_setLockIfNotPresent
  (JNIEnv * env, jclass clazz, jobject ref){
  lock.lock();
  std::map<_jobject, boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>::iterator i =mutexes.find(*ref);

    if(i == mutexes.end())
    {

        std::pair<_jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex> v
        =std::pair<_jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>(*ref, *new boost::fibers::recursive_mutex());
        mutexes.insert(v);
        lock.unlock();
        return true;
    }
   lock.unlock();
   return false;
  }
```

Below you can see the log:

```
 jni:
         [echo] Generating JNI headers
         [exec] mkdir -p target/c++
         [exec] g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -I/usr/include/boost_1_66_0  -o target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_NativeFiber.o src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_NativeFiber.cpp
         [exec] mkdir -p target/c++
         [exec] g++ -c -Wall -fPIC -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/linux -I/usr/include/boost_1_66_0  -o target/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.o src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.cpp
         [exec] src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.cpp: In function ‘jboolean Java_ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock_setLockIfNotPresent(JNIEnv*, jclass, jobject)’:
         [exec] src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.cpp:21:105: error: no matching function for call to ‘std::pair<_jobject, boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>::pair(_jobject&, boost::fibers::recursive_mutex&)’
         [exec]         =std::pair<_jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>(*ref, *new boost::fibers::recursive_mutex());
         [exec]                                                                                                          ^
         [exec] In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
         [exec]                  from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
         [exec]                  from /usr/include/c++/6/map:60,
         [exec]                  from src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.cpp:3:
         [exec] /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:423:9: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args1, long unsigned int ..._Indexes1, class ... _Args2, long unsigned int ..._Indexes2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::tuple<_Args1 ...>&, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>&, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes1 ...>, std::_Index_tuple<_Indexes2 ...>)
         [exec]          pair(tuple<_Args1...>&, tuple<_Args2...>&,
         [exec]          ^~~~
         [exec] /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:423:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
         [exec] src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.cpp:21:105: note:   ‘_jobject’ is not derived from ‘std::tuple<_Args1 ...>’
         [exec]         =std::pair<_jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>(*ref, *new boost::fibers::recursive_mutex());
         [exec]                                                                                                          ^
         [exec] In file included from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_algobase.h:64:0,
         [exec]                  from /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_tree.h:63,
         [exec]                  from /usr/include/c++/6/map:60,
         [exec]                  from src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.cpp:3:
         [exec] /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:356:9: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args1, class ... _Args2> std::pair<_T1, _T2>::pair(std::piecewise_construct_t, std::tuple<_Args1 ...>, std::tuple<_Args2 ...>)
         [exec]          pair(piecewise_construct_t, tuple<_Args1...>, tuple<_Args2...>);
         [exec]          ^~~~
         [exec] /usr/include/c++/6/bits/stl_pair.h:356:9: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
         [exec] src/main/c++/ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock.cpp:21:105: note:   ‘boost::fibers::recursive_mutex’ is not derived from ‘std::tuple<_Args1 ...>’
         [exec]         =std::pair<_jobject , boost::fibers::recursive_mutex>(*ref, *new boost::fibers::recursive_mutex());
         [exec]                                                                                                          ^
```

Comment: I don't see a pointer here.  What am I missing?

Comment: 1) You aren't inserting any pointers into your map.  2) mutexes aren't copyable (and `_jobject`s probably aren't either).  3) `*new boost::fibers::recursive_mutex()` is a memory leak.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue has nothing to do with pointers.  The problem is that the object types you're trying to store in your map are not copyable, so you can't construct them and then copy them into the map.  Instead, you can tell the map to construct them directly in place:

```
std::map<jobject, boost::fibers::recursive_mutex> mutexes;
boost::fibers::recursive_mutex lock;

JNIEXPORT jboolean JNICALL
Java_ext_concurrent_fiber_FiberLock_setLockIfNotPresent(JNIEnv* env, jclass clazz, jobject ref)
{
    std::lock_guard<boost::fibers::recursive_mutex> lck(lock);

    auto i = mutexes.find(ref);
    if(i == mutexes.end())
    {
        mutexes.emplace(std::piecewise_construct,
                        std::forward_as_tuple(ref),
                        std::tuple<>{});
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Here, I've used [`std::map::emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) along with `std::pair`'s [`std::piecewise_construct` constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/pair) to tell the map to construct its elements in place.  That way, the mutex won't need to be copied into the map.

Comment: wow thanks ... it is also more complex in c++ than how i expected :)

Comment: sorry but the new mutex is created with std::tuple<>{}?

Comment: `std::tuple<>{}` creates an empty tuple.  That tuple contains the parameters that will be passed to the mutex's constructor.  Since `recursive_mutex`'s constructor takes no parameters, you pass an empty tuple.